# How can I upgrade bash to >= 4.1 on CentOS 5.5?

Tags: centos, bash, yum

I have a CentOS 5.5 VPS server.

I want to use [RVM](https://rvm.io).

According to the console output when I run the RVM installer, RVM requires bash >= 4.1.

I just ran `yum update`. My bash version is now 3.2.25.

If I understand how yum works, that means that 3.2.25 is sort of the version of bash that "belongs with" my CentOS version, and it's the latest version I can get using yum. (Right? Or am I wrong about this?)

How can I get that on my CentOS 5.5 system?

To clarify, I understand that I can just download the source and install, but I'm hesitant to break out of yum's version management system. Is there a way to upgrade bash without disrupting yum?

Comment: `$ \curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby`
--->
`BASH 3.2.25 required`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly. Grab the SRPM from Fedora and rebuild using mock. Note that this will *not quite* work with yum since you'll have to handle updates yourself by repeating the procedure.